# Question related to calculation of probality?

Tags: probability

**question given in my text book**

> There are three events A, B and C out of which only one and one can happen. The odds are 8 to 3 against A and 5 to 2 against B. Find odd against C.

**Solution in my textbook**

Let the total no. of cases = $m + n + p$

$m$ are in favor of $A$, $n$ are in favor of $B$ and $p$ in favor of $C$

we have $\frac{n+p}{m} = \frac{8}{3}$, $\frac{m+p}{n} = \frac{5}{2}$, so that

$$P(A') = \frac{n + p}{m+n+p}=\frac{8}{11}, P(B') =\frac{m +p}{m+n+p}=\frac{5}{7}$$

i am really not able to understand what they did here right from the beginning can anyone explain it to please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their use of numbers ‘in favor of’ an event seems to me a very odd way of expressing what’s going on, so I’ll use rather different language.

The odds against $A$ are $8$ to $3$; you can think of that as meaning that for every $3$ times that $A$ does happen, on average there are $8$ times when $A$ does not happen. That is, in $8$ out of $11$ tries, on average, $A$ does **not** happen, so $\frac8{11}$ is the probability that $A$ does **not** happen. $\Bbb P(A)$, the probability that $A$ **does** happen, is therefore $1-\frac8{11}=\frac3{11}$. Similarly, the odds against $B$ are $5$ to $2$, so on average $B$ fails to occur $5$ times out of $7$, and $\frac57$ is therefore the probability that $B$ does **not** occur. $\Bbb P(B)$, the probability that $B$ **does** occur, is therefore $1-\frac57=\frac27$.

Since $A$ and $B$ cannot occur simultaneously, the probability that one or the other occurs is simply $$\Bbb P(A)+\Bbb P(B)=\frac3{11}+\frac27=\frac{21+22}{77}=\frac{43}{77}\;.$$

The problem doesn’t actually say so, but apparently we are to assume that exactly one of $A,B$, and $C$ must occur. This means that $\frac{43}{77}$ is simply the probability that $C$ does **not** occur, and therefore the probability that $C$ **does** occur is

$$\Bbb P(C)=1-\frac{43}{77}=\frac{34}{77}\;.$$

Comment: thanks sir for your fast response

Comment: @Akash: You’re welcome.